# Why does pagination create duplicates in Google's results?

Tags: 8

I created multiple views to display different types of nodes on my site. On each of these views, I added a pagination, which creates duplicates in Google's results. Why?

I think this is bad for the SEO of my site. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely bad for SEO.

You need to set related links on the each page of the view so that google doesn't crawl all of the variations via parameters. Example:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://example.com/view?page=2">
```

Apparently the [metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) will help with this, or you can find some discussion about how to do it on [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2502453).